# My manager has stoped responding to my messages and email suddenly and im on maternity leave due to return soon

Tags: communication

I'm currently at the last 3 weeks of a 6 month maternity leave. My boss always responded to my texts but suddenly has stopped responding. Could there be a problem?

Comment: How long since your boss doesn't respond? What is your location? What is your role in the company? More context will help us help you better :)

Comment: Have you contacted HR about return date etc etc They may say your boss is on hol, business trip etc

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, your boss is too busy with the work at the company. It could be that the boss suddenly faces an urgent issue or new deadline at work.

If you have specific questions on your benefits during maternal leave, then he may think that questions are best answered by HR.

If you have specific questions related your current project or role, then he may think that he should give your time to rest during your maternity leave, and then you can talk to him more when you come back.

Comment: "urgent issue [...] at work" or maybe just on sick leave or holiday. Unfortunately, bosses get sick, too.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm currently at the last 3 weeks of a 6 month maternity leave. My boss always responded to my texts but suddenly has stopped responding. Could there be a problem?

We would be guessing if we told you if there is or not a problem. However, I guess you need their input for something you are doing, so here are some alternatives I can think of:

- Pick up the phone an call your boss.
- Different countries? Whatsapp call.
- Email/Text/Call your boss's assistant/secretary
- Email/Text/Call anyone else that is on-site inquiring about boss and their availability (perhaps boss is on leave?)

When any of those work you will have more information to proceed (either on reaching your boss or succeed on reaching them).